# java.lang.VerifyError: com/parse/ManifestInfo

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm using Parse api for my application.
I got this exception from some users ( about 1 out of 1000)
I searched a lot and didn't find any solution relevant to this error, The Exception throws when calling `Parse.initialize` :

```
java.lang.VerifyError: com/parse/ManifestInfo
at com.parse.Parse.allParsePushIntentReceiversInternal(SourceFile:197)
at com.parse.Parse.initialize(SourceFile:134)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1025)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4551)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:631)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(Native Method)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:163)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

why this exception occurs for only few users? could it be something to do with Parse.com servers ?

thanks.

Comment: Do you have any more details?

Comment: This line would suggest to me that you have a problem with your push notifications? : com.parse.Parse.allParsePushIntentReceiversInternal(SourceFile:197). I couldn't tell you whats wrong without having more detail

Comment: What else you need to know ? `Parse.initialize()` is called inside Application class, so when the user lunches the app, the exception occurs. I recently sent a push notification but I also got this error for over a month ago from some users.